# Why does Ba'alzamon want Rand to drink in his dreams?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In the first several books of the Wheel of Time, Ba'alzamon appears to Rand, Mat, and Perrin in their dreams, which unless I'm mistaken we later learn is probably Tel'aran'rhiod. Among other things, Ba'alzamon seems over-eager to get them to drink something. I could never figure out why this is. Is he trying to poison them? Is it something that will make them susceptible to his influence or compulsion? Something that will help him locate them in the real world?

Is there an explanation for this in the books?

Comment: It's not explained, but  he wanted to use Rand, so that would be probably something to incapacitate them, perhaps so they would keep sleeping.

Comment: * *carefully setting aside my cup* *

Comment: Haha! I was wondering if you'd chime in...

Comment: I'd say it's likely some means which he can use to locate them in the real world. He finds them in Baerlon somehow, after which Mat is appearing guilty when Moiraine wonders how they could have been found. So maybe he drank and maybe that's how the myrddraal found them. This is all just speculation though.

Comment: @Amarth Thing is even in Tel'aran'rhiod a drink is just a drink, and there's no such thing as "magical potion" in the series.

Comment: @Mithoron That's clearly wrong, since Nynaeve conjures Forkroot tea in Tel'aran'rhiod and forces Moghedien to drink it. If others who (unlike Nynaeve) aren't skilled herbalists can do the same, we don't know.

Comment: @Amarth You're just illustrating my point there. - this tea was just like normal and we have no reason whatsoever to think it was "magical", so what your point is?

Comment: @Mithoron Who said anything about magic? (Though actually the goblet could be a ter'angreal for all we know.) My point is that Nynaeve uses this very trick to catch Moghedien.

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, didn't Moraine tell the Trio to not accept anything or agree to anything in their dreams? Maybe I'm misremembering. Perhaps it is a plothole that Jordan planned to use and dropped later

Comment: I don't have the references to create an answer from this, but I think the Wise Ones point out on a few occasions that interactions with things others bring into Tel'aran'rhiod, make you ever more susceptible to being dragged into their version of Tel'aran'rhiod, i.e. their additions to it, or even away into their dreams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I cannot find a concrete answer as to *why* Ba'alzamon or Lanfer would want any of the trio to drink in the dream; although many believe that it is most likely *not* poison, and it could possibly be a ploy to either keep them in *Tel'aran'rhiod*, or to spike them with *Forkroot*, or even possibly a way to track them (and giving Mat his *brilliant luck*).

On the *not poison* front we have:

> On that topic, what was in the goblet?  **Surely not poison**.  We know how much Ishamael wants Rand, needs Rand, to fulfill **certain prophecies and schemes** of the Shadow.  Ishamael needs the Dragon in order to complete his plans
>   <sub>[Dragonmount - emphasis mine](https://dragonmount.com/news/theoryblog/wot-if%E2%80%A6-rand-drank-from-the-goblet-r702/)</sub>

It does make sense that it wouldn't be poison, Ishameal is smart enough to know Rand (or however they think is the Dragon at this point) needs to stay alive, and can't be killed (at this stage).

On the *keep them in Tel'aran'rhiod* front: Emily, from [Everybody Hates Rand](https://www.everybodyhatesrand.com/), draws a comparison to Hades and Persephone; in which you cannot eat or drink anything from the Underworld, otherwise you are kept there forever:

> Hades and the Underworld once Persephone eats the pomegranate seeds she can’t leave. That also is tied in with fairy tales, literally tales, myths about fairies, where if **you go into the world of the fair folk** and you ***eat or drink*** any of their stuff than basically they can keep you which is freaky...
>   <sub>[Everybody Hates Rand Transcript - p14 - emphasis mine](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5bf4b371f7939280b5c4696e/t/5c0d9a3a8a922dfd481545ea/1544395324265/EHR+Episode+4+Transcript+.pdf)</sub>

Which would make sense, if you eat, or drink in this case, an offering your soul is therefore tied to whoever gave you that offering.

From the *tor reread*, and again from *Everyone Hates Rand* we also note that there is no one reason why any of the trio refuse the drink from either Ba'alzamon or Lanfear (who tries to get Perrin to drink, and he inadvertently refuses the drink when actually refusing the call of the wolves)

> And then there’s the blood-red wine that both he and Lanfear kept trying to **get Perrin to drink - Ba'alzamon tried to get Rand to drink spiced wine** from a goblet in the very first dream he appeared in, and **we still don’t know what would happen** if anyone actually accepted one and drank from it. Nothing good, obviously, but I really would like more info on what Ba'alzamon—and now Lanfear too—is trying to accomplish. Is the drink poison? Does it establish some connection between the giver and the drinker? Is it like accepting the Dark One but for Forsaken folks instead?
>   <sub>[Tor Reread - emphasis mine](https://www.tor.com/2019/03/12/reading-the-wheel-of-time-liking-what-you-become-in-robert-jordans-the-dragon-reborn-part-3/)</sub>
>
> The next thing the dude tries to do is get Rand to drink from this goblet of wine, and again, **don’t really know what would have happened** if Rand had drunk from this. We don’t know what is happening here
>   <sub>[Everybody Hates Rand Transcript - p14 - emphasis mine](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5bf4b371f7939280b5c4696e/t/5c0d9a3a8a922dfd481545ea/1544395324265/EHR+Episode+4+Transcript+.pdf)</sub>

Regarding the tracking of the trio, we can look to Theoryland, and see that the writer there speculates that although Rand and Perrin forsook the drink, Mat actually gave in:

> Pg. 66, 67 Ba'alzamon offers Perrin a drink like he did for Rand in the first book in the Dream (tEotW; pg 203). Perrin declines the drink, and Ba'alzamon’s reaction is the same as it was for Rand. Rage, disappointment, etc. Perrin does this to Lanfear too, right after he does it to Ishamael.
>
> This is Mat's mistake in The Eye. All three of them had a dream in Baerlon, and I think Ba'alzamon killed a rat for all three of them too. They spoke of the dream together, and it was the same for all three. Whether or not **all three were offered a drink**, we can only guess, but I believe they all were offered drinks (why not?), and that Perrin, like Rand in the first book, turned down the drink as he does twice more in this book. Mat, on the other hand, we don’t know. Maybe **he did drink that very first time**, and that is what helped Ishamael keep so **many of his underlings hounding them** constantly
>   <sub>[Theoryland - emphasis mine](https://www.theoryland.com/chronicles.php?user=eclipse&page=f)</sub>

The writer does go on to say that perhaps it is the knife that is the beacon, but after two days could it really have been that strong of a beacon?

Theoryland continues on to suggest that Mat's luck actually comes from him drinking form the goblet, and therefore forging a link between the two:

> Under the influence of the dagger, Mat let down his guard for the fatherly man in his dreams giving sage advice, and a **link to the Dark One was forged** with a “*drink*.” Mat now has a very logical reason for his supernaturally augmented luck.
>   <sub>[Theoryland - emphasis mine](https://www.theoryland.com/chronicles.php?user=eclipse&page=f)</sub>

The writer does go on to say that it's perhaps Mat's luck that allows the Dark One's luck to change and give him this sort of *ultra-luck* though.

And finally, on the Forkroot front, we can look to an interview with Robert Jordan on [Theoryland](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=drink) about whether or not drinking something in *Tel'aran'rhiod* will affect you in the real world. And if the trio did, then it would perhaps effect them the same way that it would in the real world:

> **Bradley Staples**
>   Can you explain a bit about the properties of the World of Dreams? Such as when Nynaeve forced Moghedien to drink forkroot tea, which caused the Forsaken to fall asleep. But within that same book, the Wise Ones tell Egwene that drinking tea will in *Tel'aran'rhiod* will cause no effects upon the body.
>
> **Robert Jordan**
>   It's a strong matter of belief. If **you believe something like that will happen to you, then it can and does**.
>   [Theoryland - emphasis mine](https://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=drink)

So we can conclude that we *really don't know* why Ba'alzamon or Lanfear want Rand (or the trio) to drink anything, but there are some speculations.

Personally, my belief is that it works similar to Persephone and Hades, and that consuming something offered by these two will somehow 'link' them together, and allow them to be tracked or influenced against their will.

Comment: This is a good thorough answer, though I disagree with the Hades and "bond with the dark one" theories.